# RangeError: Invalid Time Value when querying by date in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore database where I'm adding some documents with `timestamp` fields like so:

```js
async function addNewAppointment(appointment) {
    appointment.appointmentDate = new Date(appointment.appointmentDate)
    await setDoc(doc(db, 'appointments', appointment.appointmentID), appointment)
}
```

Here's how it looks like in firestore:

```
...
appointmentDate: February 1, 2023 at 11:00:00 AM UTC+5:30
...
```

Edit: Added images
[image: Timestamp1]
[image: Timestamp2]
When querying it like so:

```js
async function getAllAppointments(options = { date: {} }) {
    const constraints = []
    if('from' in options.date) constraints.push(where('appointmentDate', '>=', new Date(options.date.from)))
    if('to' in options.date) constraints.push(where('appointmentDate', '<', new Date(options.date.to)))
    return (await getDocs(query(collection(db, 'appointments'), ...constraints))).docs.map(appointment => appointment.data())
}
```

I'm getting:

```
index.esm2017.js:5837  Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Invalid time value
    at Date.toISOString (<anonymous>)
    at Ba (index.esm2017.js:5837:88)
    at index.esm2017.js:18652:27
    at _m (index.esm2017.js:18686:15)
    at Sm (index.esm2017.js:18573:5)
    at index.esm2017.js:18982:13
    at Um._parse (index.esm2017.js:18983:63)
    at Um._apply (index.esm2017.js:18962:42)
    at Bm (index.esm2017.js:18952:5)
```

When looking through the expected value for [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), I saw that the `... at ...` in the middle of the timestamp is causing this issue.

I even checked and this is working:

```js
> new Date('February 1, 2023 at 11:00:00 AM UTC+5:30').toISOString()
> VM15172:1 Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value
    at Date.toISOString (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:54
(anonymous) @ VM15172:1
> new Date('February 1, 2023 11:00:00 AM UTC+5:30').toISOString()
< '2023-02-01T05:30:00.000Z'
```

What do I do? How do I query properly?

Any help is appreciated!

---

I've looked at the only two results for this error under `[google-cloud-firestore]` tag:

- [RangeError: Invalid time value'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59916942/rangeerror-invalid-time-value): No answer.
- [rangeerror (index): invalid value: valid value range is empty: 0 in flutter while getting data from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61342122/rangeerror-index-invalid-value-valid-value-range-is-empty-0-in-flutter-whil): Not related to my question.

---

I found this question:

- [Firestore query by date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000854/firestore-query-by-date-range): Not using modular sdk.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the document from the Firestore console (I'd like to verify the type of the field)?

Comment: What is the return for new Date(options.date.from) and new Date(options.date.to) ?

Comment: @LeonardoFerreira Got it! I was sending epoch as `string` to options, when I needed it in `integer`. But why then does `... at ...` not work in above example?

Comment: @JaideepShekhar The at shouldn't work, it is invalid for parsing. The best option is to sanitize and/or format the date before passing it directly to the query in ISO format.